# How can I solve this error?(Using FMOD in QT Creator)

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, fmod

After build, I saw this message.

```
g++: unrecognized option '-C:\Program Files\FMOD SoundSystem\FMOD Programmers API Windows\api\lib'
```

I added this 2 lines in `gui.pro` File

```
INCLUDEPATH += -"C:\Program Files\FMOD SoundSystem\FMOD Programmers API Windows\api\inc\"

LIBS += -"C:\Program Files\FMOD SoundSystem\FMOD Programmers API Windows\api\lib\"
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: try LIBS += L"C:/Program Files/FMOD SoundSystem/FMOD Programmers API Windows/api/lib/"

Comment: After your code, I see many errors like 
<g++: LC:/Program Files/FMOD SoundSystem/FMOD Programmers API Windows/api/lib/: Invalid argument>

Comment: try LIBS += -L"C:/Program Files/FMOD SoundSystem/FMOD Programmers API Windows/api/lib/"  ... looks like '-' was missed .. check this one for reference http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator-2.3/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html

Comment: No...I can't solve this problem.
I saw <undefined reference to `FMOD::System::setOutput(FMOD_OUTPUTTYPE)@8'>

and

<collect2: Id returned 1 exit status>
important thing,
LIBS += -L"C:/Program Files/FMOD SoundSystem/FMOD Programmers API Windows/api/lib/" exist or not, I see same error message.

Comment: it's already completely another error, not that was initially in your question ;) Tip: you need to specify exact lib file from where you use exported definitions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the include path, to the headers, without the '-' in the beginning and AFAIK also without the trailing '\':

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files\FMOD SoundSystem\FMOD Programmers API Windows\api\inc"
```

Libs needs to start with -L. But that is not enough! That just adds a path to the search paths for libraries. You also need to tell the linker which library to link with. I don't know which one you need, but for a static library called libfmod.a you would add "-lfmod", i.e.:

```
LIBS += -L"C:\Program Files\FMOD SoundSystem\FMOD Programmers API Windows\api\lib\" -lfmod
```

There are some other ways to do this. For example adding different libraries for different types of builds (debug vs. release). 
[You might want to use the Qt Creator GUI for that](https://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html)

EDIT: Exactly what I just wrote:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-project-files.html#declaring-other-libraries

EDIT2:

OK, it seems for your particular case there might be another problem. 
[This StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5305811/768656) answer states, that the FMOD library was built with the Microsoft Visual Studio Compiler and that it handles name mangling for functions different from GCC. So they say you have to use the C-API instead.

That was in 2011 though. I don't have that library or a Windows machine at hand. They unfortunately only offer the installer for download, so you have to check yourself if there is some README or Documentation available.

Comment: I did your solution.

I use FMOD::System_Create();

but <undefined reference to `FMOD_System_Create@4'> error message and <collect2: Id returned 1 exit status> message appear.

What should I do?

Comment: "ld returned 1 exist status" means that the linker failed. Maybe you are not linking with the right library. What does the documentation for your library say?
Also important (!), the MinGW/GCC toolchain is only available for 32-Bit systems. So if your library is compiled as x86-64 it won't work.