# Undefined Reference when linking FMOD library on linux

Tags: c++, linux, reference, undefined, fmod

I am creating a simple game on linux in C++ and using FMOD for the sound. I recently downloaded the latest FMOD API however when I try to use it I get an undefined reference error. From what I can see with other related questions it usually has to do with where the -lfmod tag is when compiling, however no matter where I put that tag I still encounter problems.

I followed the Debian instructions for downloading the FMOD api and library.
https://wiki.debian.org/FMOD
However when the `-I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib` didn't work I moved all the library and header files to local folders and adjusted accordingly.
I am using Debian on x86_64 architecture, if that helps.

I also followed these instructions here
https://www.fmod.com/docs/api/content/generated/platform_linux/basics.html
And using ldconfig I was able to verify that I do have libasound.so.2 downloaded in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

I am aware of this answer
[C++:Undefined reference to 'FMOD:: X'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303643/cundefined-reference-to-fmod-x)
but because I am compiling using G++ and the FMOD linux libraries were compiled using GCC I don't think there should be a problem.

Here is the error I get when compiling.

```
g++ -c audioEngine.cpp
g++ driver.o game.o uiInteract.o uiDraw.o audioEngine.o point.o velocity.o flyingObject.o ship.o bullet.o rocks.o pause.o keyBind.o asteroid.o -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lfmod -lglut -lGLU -lGL
audioEngine.o: In function `Implementation::Implementation()':
audioEngine.cpp:(.text+0x67): undefined reference to `FMOD::Studio::System::create(FMOD::Studio::System**, unsigned int)'
audioEngine.cpp:(.text+0x92): undefined reference to `FMOD::Studio::System::initialize(int, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*)'
audioEngine.cpp:(.text+0xbf): undefined reference to `FMOD::Studio::System::getLowLevelSystem(FMOD::System**) const'
audioEngine.o: In function `Implementation::~Implementation()':
audioEngine.cpp:(.text+0x13b): undefined reference to `FMOD::Studio::System::unloadAll()'
audioEngine.cpp:(.text+0x151): undefined reference to `FMOD::Studio::System::release()'
audioEngine.o: In function `Implementation::advance()':
audioEngine.cpp:(.text+0x2cf): undefined reference to `FMOD::Studio::System::update()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:21: recipe for target 'a.out' failed
make: *** [a.out] Error 1
```

Here are the problem areas in audioEngine.cpp
In the header file "fmod.hpp" and "fmod_studio.hpp" are included.

```
Implementation::Implementation()
{
  mpStudioSystem = NULL;
  AudioEngine::ErrorCheck(FMOD::Studio::System::create(&mpStudioSystem));
  AudioEngine::ErrorCheck(mpStudioSystem->initialize(32, FMOD_STUDIO_INIT_LIVEUPDATE, FMOD_INIT_PROFILE_ENABLE, NULL));

  mpSystem = NULL;
  AudioEngine::ErrorCheck(mpStudioSystem->getLowLevelSystem(&mpSystem));
}

Implementation::~Implementation()
{
  AudioEngine::ErrorCheck(mpStudioSystem->unloadAll());
  AudioEngine::ErrorCheck(mpStudioSystem->release());
}

void Implementation::advance()
{
  vector<ChannelMap::iterator> pStoppedChannels;
  for (auto it = mChannels.begin(), itEnd = mChannels.end(); it != itEnd; ++it)
  {
    bool bIsPlaying = false;
    it->second->isPlaying(&bIsPlaying);
    if (!bIsPlaying)
    {
      pStoppedChannels.push_back(it);
    }
  }
  for (auto& it : pStoppedChannels)
  {
    mChannels.erase(it);
  }
  AudioEngine::ErrorCheck(mpStudioSystem->update());
}
```

Here is the relevant part of the makefile

```
LFLAGS = -I./include -L./lib -lfmod -lglut -lGLU -lGL

###############################################################
# Build the main game
###############################################################
a.out: driver.o game.o uiInteract.o uiDraw.o audioEngine.o point.o velocity.o flyingObject.o ship.o bullet.o rocks.o pause.o keyBind.o asteroid.o
    g++ driver.o game.o uiInteract.o uiDraw.o audioEngine.o point.o velocity.o flyingObject.o ship.o bullet.o rocks.o pause.o keyBind.o asteroid.o $(LFLAGS)
```

The .so library files are in a "lib" folder in the project folder where the makefile is, and the .h and .hpp files are in an "include" folder in the same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized the answer to this question moments before posting, but I spent enough time trying to figure it out I'm posing anyway for future reference if anyone else follows the Debian instructions and wonders why they get an undefined reference.

If you are including the "fmod_studio.hpp" file you also need to include the fmod studio library. Add `-lfmodstudio` after `-lfmod` and provided you have everything else right it will now compile without an undefined reference.

The solution is so obvious I feel like an idiot. Of course if I want fmodstudio I need to include the fmodstudio library! It's like I was flooring the accelerator without an engine then checking the oil.